# Не удаётся вывести тип в шаблоне

Tags: c++, c++20

```
#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <format>

template<class... Args>
struct source_message
{
     consteval source_message(std::string_view formatString, const std::source_location& _location = std::source_location::current())
         : format{ formatString }
         , location{ _location }
     {

     }

    std::format_string<Args...> format;
    std::source_location location;
};

template<class... Args>
void log_trace_f(const source_message<Args...>& format, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << format.location.function_name() << " " << std::format(format.format, std::forward<Args>(args)...) << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    // log_trace_f("{}", 123); // could not deduce template argument for 'const source_message<Args...> &' from 'const char [3]'
    log_trace_f({ "{}" }, 123); // int __cdecl main(void) 123
    
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли способ завести первый вариант?

Фактически от функции log_trace_f требуется компайл тайм проверка строки форматирования и дополнительный вывод std::source_location в неявном виде, интерфейс функции log_trace_f должен быть похож на std::format()

Comment: Зря хедеры выкинули. Любому, кто хочет скопилировать код, придется руками их обратно добавлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут две проблемы.

Во-первых, когда первый аргумент не завернут в `{...}`, компилятор пытается вывести `Args...` не только из `Args&&... args`, но и также из `const source_message<Args...>& format`. И ругается, что не может это сделать.

Не буду притворяться, что понимаю, откуда такая разница в поведении (надо закапываться в стандарт), но фикс простой - первый параметр завернуть в `type_identity`, чтобы заблокировать вывод из него шаблонных аргументов: `const std::type_identity_t<source_message<Args...>>& format`.

После этого вылезает вторая ошибка:
`no known conversion from 'const char[3]' to 'const std::type_identity_t<source_message<int>>' (aka 'const source_message<int>') for 1st argument`

Компилятор не хочет вызывать больше одного пользовательского преобразования за раз (`const char [3]` -> `std::string_view` -> `source_message<int>`). Фикс - зашаблонить конструктор `source_message`, чтобы убрать второе преобразование:

```
template <std::convertible_to<std::string_view> T>
consteval source_message(T &&format, const std::source_location &location = std::source_location::current())
    : format(std::forward<T>(format)), location(location)
{}
```

Comment: brilliant, спасибо большое. Может подскажете хорошую литературу по шаблонам в последних стандартах с++?

Comment: @goldstar_labs Стековерфлоу. :) Не знаю, я специальных книжек не читал.

Comment: По второму пункту - вроде как конструкторы у `str::string_view` explicit, поэтому и не делает конвертацию

Comment: @Mister_Jesus `explicit` у него только какой-то другой конструктор, который здесь не используется. От `const char *` - не explicit. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view

Comment: Да, все так. Проглядел, что вы уже сказали причину ошибку